# How do I revert, undo, or reverse my own edit?

Tags: support, editing

Yesterday on stackoverflow I accidentally edited someone's answer instead of my question.

I added an "Update: " and saved it then realized my mistake, and edited again, took that edit out and put it into the right spot (in my question).

But the edit that I made to the user's response still shows that I edited their answer, which might seem weird, when that user sees no differences.

So I think I might have missed out on a trick.

What if I want to completely UNDO (reverse) my own edit?  I will of course hopefully be more careful in the future, but how do you revert your own edit and leave the question not showing "edited by me, 1 minute ago".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Once you save an edit on a post it's marked in its history with you as the author of that edit.

To reverse it you can rollback the edits to the previous version.

If you were making any edits inside a five minute window they would all be rolled into the one version.

But once you crack open an edit, it's there and leaves the evidence trail.

Comment: Big brother is watching you...